# Regular expression to find and replace @ mentions like twitter

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am developing a PHP application which needs a regular expression to replace the @ mentions like twitter. Also the regular expression should satisfy the following needs.

1. if there is just `@` and nothing before and after that then it should not be replaced.
2. `@` in the emails should not be replaced. For eg. `sam@example.com` should not be replaced.
3. Only strings like `@sam` or `@example` should be replaced like `<a href="http://twitter.com/sam">@sam</a>` and `<a href="http://twitter.com/example">@example</a>`

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow. I found the answer myself guys.

```
$tweet = preg_replace('/(^|[^a-z0-9_])@([a-z0-9_]+)/i', '$1<a href="http://twitter.com/$2">@$2</a>', $tweet);
```

Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like -

```
(?<!\w)@[\w]+
```

Answer (score 1):

As twitter can contain up to 15 characters, you could write it like this to avoid some bugs:

```
$tweet = preg_replace("/(^\w)@(\w{1,15})/i", "\\1<a ref=\"http://twitter.com/\\2\">@\\2</a>", $tweet);
```